# QtQuick.Controls 2.0 stopped working suddenly

Tags: qt, qml

I am running QtCreator with msvc2017_64. Everything was working fine suddenly i am unable to load this simple qml code in QQmlApplicationEngine

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480
title: qsTr("Hello World")

Button {
    height: 50
    width: 100
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    text: "close"
    //onClicked: closeApp();
}
}
```

and when i am commenting Button then i can run application. it looks like my QtCreator suddenly stopped support for

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"unable to load this simple qml code"_ ? Do you get some error/warning?

Comment: It just gives "Application has stopped working".Even i created a lose setup(contains all related dlls) of my Qt5 App that's working on another PC, even it was working on my PC previously but i now can't execute it. App compiled on my PC are Running on another PC. I also tried re installation of QT5.

Comment: App exit code is -1073741819

Comment: [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/11332/i-always-get-the-error-code-255-but-why/5) this can be a possibility. My PC does not have any antivirus

Comment: After switching my User account i can run & compile my application. so looks like problem in environment variable somewhere